# Android NFC Sharing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have two Devices with Android NFC features.I want to send and receive some data using NFC,My requirement are to use NFC not other sharing feature.
I want to share text data only includes number and Alphabetic
Anyone can guide from where I can Start to do this ?Is there any Tutorial with example code ?
Great thanks .  .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this document by Google (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) and look for Android Beam specifically. Android Beam will allow you to send one message from one device to another when they are close to each other. There's also an example in the SDK samples.

Comment: hi ameen thanks,I just configure Beam example in eclipse,I am trying to ping other device to send it data but nothing happening . .

Comment: Hi Ameen I configured the Beam,It is running now , How I can received message on other device ?